# Strange issue with en.lproj

Tags: iphone

I am getting strange issue with localizable strings. I have added few localizable strings in en.lproj and accessing them using `NSLocalizedString(localizablestringname,nil);`

The issue is, sometimes it gives value of localizablestringname and sometimes it does not give any value when I run the application.

For example, I have added `"appTagsTitle" = "Tags";` in localizable strings, and I used appTagsTitle to be displayed on screen, sometimes it displays "Tags" on screen and sometimes it gives "appTagsTitle" on screen, so it looks like, sometimes localized strings does not work properly.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Are you always running on english?
If not, try setting the application default language to english

Comment: yes, I am always running on english language

Comment: Do you maybe include another library that also has localization files and messes with yours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Localization resource]

I have solved it, somehow resources for English Localizations were showing 2 files, check attached image. then, I deleted localizations and added again, the problem was solved.